# Vba - excel - Outlook - report Email headers and auto send message on new email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I need a little help, i completely lost in my code...

My code is to be used in different outlook accounts which use different email accounts and should export the email headers in order of arrival in a single Excel sheet (used as a database), to back-up the arriving email, mark as read and respond automatically with a number unique protocol.

Clearly if the email had already previously been processed wish that the process might pass away, and draw up only new emails arrive.

Currently my code works partially, because sometimes the arrival of a new email does not write the data in the last row of the excel spreadsheet but rather in the first row, overwriting the data that was present.

However if I use the code with another email account, the script completely erase the data in excel sheet and returns only the new data to the new email account.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve the situation?
Thanks so much.

```
This is the code:

Sub Mail_Protocol()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Dim enviro As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strColB, strColC, strColD, strColE, strColF, strColG As String
Dim objns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objName As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
Dim obj As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objItem As Object
Dim sPath As String
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim sName As String

' Get Excel set up
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
strPath = enviro & "\Desktop\DataBase.xlsx"
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Foglio1")

' Process the message record

On Error Resume Next

xlSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "prot"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "email"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "name"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 4) = "object"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 5) = "message"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 6) = "receiver"
xlSheet.Cells(1, 7) = "date"

'Find the next empty line of the worksheet

rCount = xlSheet.Cells("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rCount = rCount + 1


Set objns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objName = objns.Folders("OneOfMyEmail@email.com")
Set objFolder = objName.Folders("Posta in arrivo")
Set objItems = objFolder.Items


For Each obj In objItems

Set olItem = obj
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)


'if email value exist in databese skip to next

If xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount + 1) <> olItem.Body _
And xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount + 1) <> olItem.Subject Then

'collect the fields
strColB = olItem.SenderName
strColC = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
strColG = olItem.Subject
strColD = olItem.Body
strColE = olItem.To
strColF = olItem.ReceivedTime

'write them in the excel sheet

xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount + 1) = rCount
xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount + 1) = strColB
xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount + 1) = strColC
xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount + 1) = strColG
xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount + 1) = strColD
xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount + 1) = strColE
xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount + 1) = strColF


'-----------------Send Email Protocol--------------------
strbody = "Buongiorno," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Questo è un messsaggio generato automaticamente, si prega di non    rispondere." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "La sua email è stata correttamente ricevuta." & vbNewLine & _
      "Il suo numero protocollo è : " & rCount & vbNewLine & _
      "La sua richiesta verrà evasa quanto prima." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Distinti saluti."

On Error Resume Next
With objMsg
    .To = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "RICEZIONE EMAIL - PROTOCOLLO N. " & rCount
    .Body = strbody
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

'-----------------Backup Email---------------------------

Set oMail = obj
sName = oMail.Subject
ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
sName = "P.g." & rCount & "_" & Format(dtDate, "dd.mm.yy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _                        
vbUseSystem) & "_" & "" & sName & ".msg"
sPath = enviro & "\Desktop\"
Debug.Print sPath & sName
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
obj.UnRead = True

Else: GoTo prossimo

End If

prossimo:
rCount = rCount + 1
Next


xlWB.Close 1
If bXStarted Then
xlApp.Quit
End If

Set olItem = Nothing
Set obj = Nothing
Set Items = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, sChr As String)

sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)

End Sub
```

this should be the result

[image]

Comment: You have to see errors to fix them. Remove the On Error Resume Next that is just below ' Process the message record. If you find an error update the question with the error and indicate the highlighted line. When you use On Error Resume Next in the future follow closely with On Error GoTo 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main problem is in:

```
rCount = xlSheet.Cells("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

since Outlook knows nothing about Excel enumerations and so it evaluates `xlUp` to *zero*, thus making the `End(0)` `Range` method throw an error which would be ignored by the ruling  `On Error Resume Next` error handling which finally make `rCount` stay on its initialization value which is `zero`

so you have to either:

- use *early binding*, adding Microsoft Excel XY.Z library reference to your project

  and then

  ```
     Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
     ' ...and so on
  ```
- stay with late binding (as you are by now) and use the actual enumeration value (which is `-4162`) instead of `xlUp`

  ```
   rCount = xlSheet.Cells("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
  ```

Still not sure about your email processing flux, but you may want to consider the following partial refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mail_Protocol()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim bXStarted As Boolean
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strColB As String, strColC As String, strColD As String, strColE As String, strColF As String, strColG As String
    Dim objns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String

    MsgBox xlUp
    Set objItems = GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("OneOfMyEmail@email.com").Folders("Posta in arrivo").Items

    ' Get Excel set up
    Set xlApp = GetExcel(bXStarted) '<-- get Excel
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    'the path of the workbook
    strPath = enviro & "\Desktop\DataBase.xlsx"
    'Open the data workbook and reference its worksheet where to put them into
    With xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath).Sheets("Foglio1")

        ' write headers
        .Range("A1:G1") = Array("prot", "email", "name", "object", "message", "receiver", "date")

        'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
        rCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(-4162).Row + 1

        For Each objItem In objItems

            'if email value exist in database skip to next

            If .Range("E" & rCount + 1) <> objItem.Body _
            And .Range("D" & rCount + 1) <> objItem.Subject Then
                'write them in the excel sheet
                .Range("A" & rCount + 1).resize(, 7) = GetInfoArray(objItem, rCount)

                '-----------------Send Email Protocol--------------------
                strbody = "Buongiorno," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "Questo è un messsaggio generato automaticamente, si prega di non    rispondere." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "La sua email è stata correttamente ricevuta." & vbNewLine & _
                      "Il suo numero protocollo è : " & rCount & vbNewLine & _
                      "La sua richiesta verrà evasa quanto prima." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "Distinti saluti."

                With Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                    .To = objItem.SenderEmailAddress
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = "RICEZIONE EMAIL - PROTOCOLLO N. " & rCount
                    .Body = strbody
                    .Save
        '            .Send   'or use .Display
                End With

                '-----------------Backup Email---------------------------
                sName = ReplaceCharsForFileName(objItem.Subject, "-")
                dtDate = objItem.ReceivedTime
                sName = "P.g." & rCount & "_" & Format(dtDate, "dd.mm.yy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                vbUseSystem) & "_" & "" & sName & ".msg"
                sPath = enviro & "\Desktop\"
                Debug.Print sPath & sName
                objItem.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
                objItem.UnRead = True

            Else: GoTo prossimo

            End If

prossimo:
            rCount = rCount + 1
        Next
    End With

    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close 1
    If bXStarted Then xlApp.Quit

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function GetInfoArray(objItem As Outlook.MailItem, rCount As Long)
    With objItem
        GetInfoArray = Array(rCount, _
                            .SenderName, _
                            .SenderEmailAddress, _
                            .Subject, _
                             .Body, _
                             .To, _
                             .ReceivedTime)
    End With
End Function

Private Function ReplaceCharsForFileName(ByVal sName As String, sChr As String) As String
    sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
    ReplaceCharsForFileName = sName
End Function


Private Function GetExcel(bXStarted As Boolean) As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bXStarted = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set GetExcel = xlApp
End Function
```

where you see I also removed nearly all those `On Error Resume Next`, which is almost *always* a bad coding practice, with very few exceptions (like in the `Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` statement)

Comment: your tips are great!!  The function to create arrays is fantastic! more i didn't activated the library references.
Now I have only one problem the script does not recognize me emails already processed listed inside the database, and every time I start the program it creates duplicates in excel sheet.
Do you have some advice?
Also do you think it would be possible to use a databese sql instead that an excel spreadsheet? Would you recommend it?
Sorry for the many questions but use VBA recently and I'm a true newbe.
Thanks so much!!

Comment: you are welcome. As for the new issues you'd better post a new question and tailor it to the minimum code required to have people understand it and give you meaningful answers. Anyhow for the duplicate issue you could use the [Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) function and add a check for columns content (or part of them, using `LookAt :=xlPart` parameter specification) . As for the database sql vs Excel I do think it's possibile to switch to the former, more, it's preferable when database are sufficiently big